# Relevance of gold badge tags on questions single-handedly closed as duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I've encountered a number of cases where I disagreed with already made decisions to close questions as duplicates. I would generally cast a "reopen" vote, hope for the best, and move on.

A question being "duplicate" in essence can sometimes be a subject of debate, irrespective of the number of people who made the decision. So is a "reopen" opinion.

There is, however, the case of "gold badges" in ***irrelevant*** tags, which I personally think aggravates the problem.

[One such question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203586/installing-jar-in-local-mvn-repository-succeeds-but-still-cannot-be-found) was tagged `java`+`maven`+`jar`, and was single-handedly closed by a `java` gold badge holder. The question, however, is **all** about `maven`.

It seems to me that allowing a question to be single-handedly closed by a gold-badge holder of **any** of the tags on the question is not completely correct. Tags are often added to questions carelessly and there is no indication of "tag relevance" or "tag weight".

So, are gold badge holders required to verify the relevance of their gold badge in the context of the question, or does the system do anything to ensure that hammers aren't in the right hands at the wrong time?

Comment: Ironically, the question was reopened by a gold-badged [tag:java] user.

Comment: @Nicol It's the same user ;)

Comment: It is impossible to know which tags are relevant and which ones aren't. That is also subjective.

Comment: The gold badge holders for specific tags are usually trusted to use that feature in a useful manner, yes. Another gold badge holder for a combined tag can reopen that question equally well, if they think that the duplicate wasn't justified or helpful (even beyond a simple _off-topic_ close vote).

Answer (score 13):

> It seems to me that allowing a question to be single-handedly closed by a gold-badge holder of any of the tags on the question is not completely correct.

It's not a question of being "completely correct". It's a question of how much more likely they are to be right than wrong.

Sometimes they get it wrong. It happens. In the case you've cited here, the closer themselves reopened it. The edits convinced them that it wasn't a duplicate, or they realized they closed the question in error. Either way, the system seemed to work.

Any mistakes made by gold-badge holders can be corrected, either by 5 regular users or by other gold-badge holders (or as in this case, the same one). So while some things do get dupe-hammered incorrectly, the system is not without a way to handle that.